# Why is - $\frac{8}{17}$ taken instead of $\frac{8}{17}$ when trying to find the $cos x$ from $\tan x = \frac{15}{8}$ and $\in [\pi, \dfrac{3\pi}{2}]$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

$\sec^2 (x) =  \tan^2 (x) + 1$

$\sec^2 (x) = \left(\dfrac{15}{8}\right)^2 + 1$

$\sec (x) = \pm \sqrt{\dfrac{289}{64}}$

$\sec (x) = - \dfrac{17}{8}$ because $x \in \left[\pi, \dfrac{3\pi}{2}\right]$ <--- This is where I don't understand why we take the negative.

Comment: draw the graph of cos, and hence, sec. What is the output range at your desired domain?

Comment: I suspect the title should read $\tan x = \frac{15}{8}$

Comment: @BenjaminWang I'm not sure to understand what you mean but the graph of sec is the one of 1/cos right?

Comment: All angles in the interval $[\pi,\frac{3\pi}2]$ have negative secants (because they have negative cosines).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the primary trigonometric ratios ($\sin, \cos, \tan$) are only all non-negative in the first quadrant. In the other three quadrants, exactly one is non-negative.

Your angle is in the third quadrant, where only tangent is non-negative. You expect to get a negative cosine here. The secant is the reciprocal of the cosine, so it shares the same sign. That's why you take the negative value.

A useful memory aid [here](https://www.onlinemath4all.com/astc-formula.html).

Answer (score 0):

Further to Deepak's answer: so the mnemonic that I used when growing up was "All Science Teachers are Crazy".

But beyond mnemonics, it is instructive to study the following diagram (noting that angles are positive if and only if measured anti-clockwise)
[image]

and understand that the +/- sign of any trigonometric ratio is derived from the +/- signs of the corresponding $x$- and $y$- coordinates.

E.g., $\displaystyle \cot(100°)=\frac{\cos(100°)}{\sin(100°)},\quad$ so $\cot(100°)$ is $\frac-+=$ negative.

Comment: Haha leave it to a math teacher to say All Science Teachers (are) Crazy. 