# With a negative fraction, which number is negative, the denominator or the numerator? (For determining the quadrant of an angle from a trig value.)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, fractions

I'm in Pre-Calculus and were doing trigonometry and their functions, so I have to figure out which number on the fraction is negative.

For example: $\cos x=-(5/8)$ on the 2nd quadrant and I have to find $\tan x$ and $\csc x$. $\csc x$ is easy, because all I have to do is flip the numbers and I don't have to worry which number is negative. But with $\tan x$, I do need to know.

Thanks!

Comment: Both $\frac{-5}8$ and $\frac 5{-8}$ are equal to $-\frac 58$.

Comment: It's your choice!  $-\left( \frac{5}{8}\right) = \frac{-5}{8} = \frac{5}{-8}$.

Comment: If $\cos x$ is negative, then you can't tell if it's in the 2nd or 3rd quadrant, unless you're given more info.

Comment: If the angle $x$ is in the 2nd quadrant, then you can [deduce](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4071513/21813) that $\cos(x)$, $\tan(x)$ and $\csc(x)$ are negative, negative and positive respectively. *Additionally*, the absolute value $\frac58$ of $\cos(x)$ enables you to compute the value of any trigonometric function of this $x$.